# How to add spacing to a table using tailwind

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I was trying to add space to the table but I was unable to do it. I have tried using `space-x-`, padding but I was not getting the output I was anticipated.

[Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jhcHfKk6DX)

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<table class="table-auto">
  <tr class="row space-x-3">
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">42.80</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">42.80</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">52.51</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">60.40</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">96.28</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">69.18</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">54.43</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">69.18</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">96.28</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">60.40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">42.80</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">42.80</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">52.51</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">60.40</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">96.28</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">69.18</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">54.43</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">69.18</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">96.28</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">60.40</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 </html>
```

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: You would add [`border-separate`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-collapse#separate) to the table class.

Comment: The short answer is to add both `border-separate` and `border-spacing-*` classes to the table element. The first class gives each cell its own border and the second lets you specify the space between them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`border-separate` does its job for separations.
If you want more control (on degrees of separation), you can add,
[border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) property.

But there are no utilities for `border-spacing` for TW.

[TW doc on spacing](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space) shows `space-x-3` as, `margin-left: 0.75rem;`
So you'd need to `border-spacing: 0.75rem`.

You can add a custom utility (or component) in your Tailwind CSS file.

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .my-table-spacing {
    border-spacing: theme("spacing.3");
  }
}
```

And use it like `<table class="border-separate my-table-spacing">`.

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/qAFB4JGLvo?file=css

But with Tailwind CSS v3.0, you can add [arbitrary properties](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties).
Thus, you can add `[border-spacing:0.75rem]` as an arbitrary property
as shown below.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<table class="border-separate [border-spacing:0.75rem]">
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">42.80</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">42.80</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">52.51</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">60.40</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">96.28</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">69.18</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">54.43</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">69.18</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">96.28</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">60.40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">42.80</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">42.80</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">52.51</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">60.40</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">96.28</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">69.18</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">54.43</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">69.18</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">96.28</td>
    <td class="col bg-blue-500">60.40</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also on TW Playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/UYWXm7PTEo

Comment: It seems border spacing utilities are available now https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-spacing

Answer (score 5):

If you apply padding to the `<table><table/>` tag like this:

```html
<table class="p-8"><table/>
```

This won't work, you need to add the `border-separate` property in addition, and we will finally have:

```html
<table class="border-separate p-8"><table/>
```